# Where can I eat sushi with chocolate in it?

Tags: japan, food-and-drink, brazil, local-cuisine

In 2012, then Tokyo Governor Shintaro Ishihara [said](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shintaro_Ishihara#Other_controversial_statements) (in Japanese)

> Westerners practicing judo resembles beasts fighting.
>   Internationalized judo has lost its appeal.
>
> In Brazil they put chocolate in norimaki, but I wouldn't call it
>   sushi. Judo has gone the same way.

However, doing a search for "chocolate sushi", or even "chocolate sushi Brazil", doesn't seem to provide any info on sushi with chocolate in it being an established item, or at least a trend (akin to [deep fried Mars bars in Scotland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep-fried_Mars_bar)), in any location's cuisine, as opposed to it occurring only at a particular restaurant.

Is chocolate in sushi a thing, and if so, where can I eat it?

Comment: It might have been unsweetened cacao as opposed to chocolate. I can see that being used as a mild seasoning on fish, and it's a pretty standard ingredient around there. (IMHO, the real story here is how nobody sees such statements as chauvinist racism or xenophobia, but many just take them at face value…)

Comment: @Potatoswatter Regarding the "real story", Ishihara has made many "controversial" statements. The fact that the Wikipedia section is labelled "Other controversial statements" says something about him.

Comment: "Sushi" just means "vinegared rice". "Norimaki" just means "seaweed roll". Putting innovative ingredients in and not removing the vinegar, rice, or seaweed doesn't make it not one. It just makes it not a traditional one. Just like deep frying a Mars Bar doesn't turn it into "not a Mars Bar". Doesn't mean Shintaro has to like newfangled stuff.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you do a search with the terms *sushi com chocolate* (sushi with chocolate) you will find plenty of recepies. Nevertheless, it's certainly not a trend, I have ate sweet sushi before but I had never heard of norimaki with chocolate before.

It's really common to find sweet temakis ("sweet kones") for dessert, I wouldn't be surprised to find one with chocolate, but they certainly don't have fish on them :) They are not temaki in my opinion, as they are normally not rolled in nori.

It depends on where you are, but I'd search for *temaki doce* (sweet temaki), along with the name of the city where you are to find places to eat.

[image]

Comment: Well technically, if we want to use such a word, "temaki" just means "hand rolled" so doesn't technically imply use of nori.

Comment: I wouldn't use the meaning of the word to define the food, otherwise we could call mahshi malfuf a temaki :) But what I meant is that it's so different that I wouldn't consider it a temaki.

Comment: You distinguish between meaning and definition?? What do you mean when you use the word "technically" then? \-:

Comment: Yeah, that was misused :)

Answer (score 9):

Try searching for "temaki de chocolate" instead.  Searching for '"temaki de chocolate" Brasilia', for instance, got me the [Sushiloko chain](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fguia.uol.com.br%2Fbrasilia%2Frestaurantes%2Fdetalhes.htm%3Fponto%3Dsushiloko_4099420908&ei=i1oEVLu9OILdaNuegqgL&usg=AFQjCNGy_NhsY-NQ2u0jZOrNCBweqeMSjA&sig2=x4rMP2FslOucHdQmT6xLdg&bvm=bv.74115972,d.d2s) and a number of other restaurant mentions (I think - I don't speak Portuguese).  It looks as if temaki with chocolate and banana, in particular, is certainly not unheard of.